# Rails/RSpec ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR when running specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I've been googling around and trying different solutions I've found on Stackoverflow but can't seem to find a solution.

I've tried dropping recreating re seeding my database.....I blew postgres out and reinstalled...

tried to restart my sequence via the rails console

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each { |t| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t) }
```

I tried dropping the table that was having the issue and re running migrations......

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
    PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_monthly_recordable_and_end_of_month_date"
    DETAIL:  Key (monthly_recordable_id, monthly_recordable_type, end_of_month_date)=(19, Actual, 2011-08-31) already exists.
    : INSERT INTO "monthly_records" ("monthly_recordable_type","monthly_recordable_id","end_of_month_date","end_of_quarter_date","actuals_import_batch_id","production","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ('Actual',19,'2011-08-31','2011-09-30',13,244.0,'2016-07-22 21:07:47.183392','2016-07-22 21:07:47.183402'),('Actual',19,'2011-07-31','2011-09-30',13,432.0,'2016-07-22 21:07:47.183392','2016-07-22 21:07:47.183402'),('Actual',19,'2011-06-30','2011-06-30',13,992.0,'2016-07-22 21:07:47.183392','2016-07-22 21:07:47.183402')RETURNING id
```

any help would be appreciated......

The application was working fine........but I had to reclone the project and set it up again when this started happening

Comment: Is `monthly_records` empty prior to your insert? If so, are you certain it is not being called twice?

Comment: how can i verify that its not being called twice?

Comment: One way would be to remove the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` from the table and run your program. If the data is duplicated, then you know it is running more than once.

Comment: i really dont think its anything wrong with the code since no one else is having this issue...and on my laptop it works fine.....I just checked the migration file and there is no unique constraint set nor in the model.....

Comment: So you don't want to rule that out with a relatively simple test??

Comment: There is a unique constraint - an index: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_monthly_recordable_and_end_of_month_date"`

Comment: I'm willing to try anything at this point but im not seeing anything in the migration like :unique => true.....is that what I'm trying to look for?

Comment: The error message itself is telling you that you are violating a unique constraint. At this point it matters not what you see in the code - there is a unique index on that table. You mentioned that you have already dropped the table, dropped the database, reinstalled PostgreSQL - yet you won't try dropping the index? `DROP INDEX index_monthly_recordable_and_end_of_month_date;`

Comment: Sounds like you might have spec leakage (data from one is leaking into another). Next time it fails note the "random seed" rspec ran with and have a colleague run it with the same seed. Good chance it will fail for them.